# Print characters from list with a For-loop

Tags: functions, core-language

Suppose I have the list

```
primary = {"b","a","e"}
```

I want to get the following output with a For-loop (or While-loop)

"b"
"a"
"e"

My code is:

```
For[i = 0, i < 3, Part[primary, i], i++]
```

but there was no Output.

Comment: `For` loops and `Print` statements aren't used in *Mathematica* in the same way as in other languages (well, you can, but it's usually not a good idea). See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134609/26598) and [`Print`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Print.html) or [`Echo`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Echo.html).

Comment: `Print /@ primary;`

Comment: How about TableForm[primary] or Column[primary].

Answer (score 8):

Some things:

1. For-loops are for effect; they always return `Null`, which doesn't print.
2. Your For-loop is mal-formed.
3. Mathematica arrays are 1-based, not 0-based.
4. To get printed output you need to use `Print` or some other function that produces an output cell.

Taking the above into consideration, the minimal correction to your code is:

```
For[i = 1, i <= 3, i++, Print[Part[primary, i]]]
```

But here is a much better way to do the same thing.

```
Scan[Print, primary]
```

This writes the each character in own output cell.

[image: multi_cell]

#### Update

Another very simple solution you might consider is

```
Column[primary]
```

This writes each character on its own line is a **single** output cell.

[image: one_cell]

Answer (score 2):

You might try the code as in the following transcript:

```
Mathematica 10.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (32-bit)
Copyright 1988-2015 Wolfram Research, Inc.

In[1]:= primary = {"b", "a", "e"};

In[2]:= Map[ Print @ InputForm @ # &, primary];
"b"
"a"
"e"

In[3]:=
```

which seems to be what you want.

The `InputForm` is a print format which shows the double quotes delimiting the strings. The `Print @ InputForm @ # &` is an idiomatic way of defining an anonymous function which prints an exmpression using the print format. The `Map[]` applies the function to all the elements of the list. As usual in Mathematica there are several variant ways to do something like what you wanted to do. One variant would be to use `Scan[]` instead of `Map[]` which has the advantage that the trailing `;` would not be needed. Here is another variation using `Do[]`

```
In[3]:= Do[ Print @ InputForm @ s, {s , primary}]
"b"
"a"
"e"

In[4]:=
```

Comment: A slot free version is `Print@*InputForm /@ primary`.

Comment: @Carl Woll Yes, but `@*` is not yet defined in Mathemathica 10.2.

Comment: Are you sure? I think it was introduced in M10, and it does work in my copy of M10.

Comment: @CarlWoll Actually, you are correct, but I almost never use `Composition` although it can be useful.